# dpkg doesn't function properly after upgrading an AWS EC2 to 14.04

Tags: python, dpkg, amazon-ec2

After running `do-release-upgrade -d` on our staging EC2 instance, I've encountered a problem with dpkg.

My original problem was that mkvirtualenv command was failing with the following error:

`Unknown distribution  virtual 1.7.11`

and some details I cannot recover, because I've erased python :(

But once I've removed python manually, and tried to re-install it, I started getting the following error at the rnd of the apt-get install process:

```
Setting up python-twisted-names (11.1.0-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-names.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-names.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-twisted-names (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up python-twisted-web (11.1.0-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-web.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-web.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-twisted-web (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-twisted-names
 python-twisted-web
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reinstalling dpkg?
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg`

If this doesn't work, this may be specific to the pythons packages.
Try to modify the postinst file: `gksu gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-twisted-names.postinst` or another text editor if you prefer.

Delete all the content and replace by

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exit 0
```

If this still doesn't do it, you can try deleting the status file `rm /var/lib/dpkg/status` and leave it like that so a new one is built, or replace it with the old one `cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status`

I also know these commands `dpkg --configure -a` and `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a`, they should be useful but I don't know when. Try them at different points. Don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` at least once before the configure.

Comment: Tried re-installing, did not work
Will try the other 2 ones, and if they don't work, I'll create the instance all over again - no other choice

Comment: second option gives the following error : `-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Comment: After deleting the status file: `E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
`

Comment: The thing with the .postinst file is a bit tinkering cause you don't actually modify dpkg nor the python package but it worked for me :p I'm no pro in Ubuntu so I don't know the whys and hows, but this solved my similar problem when I was trying to install additional dbus packages

Comment: Ok, try copying the old one then, I must have gotten mixed up

Comment: So, did you have to reinstall the whole system? Or did you find a fix?

Comment: Re-installed whole system eventually